# A relation of some weight distribution

Tags: coding-theory

Let $C$ be a binary code and let $\overline{C}$ be the extended code of $C$ obtained by adding an overall parity check. 
**Is it true that**

> $W_{\overline{C}}(x)=\frac{1}{2}[(1+x)W_C (x)+(1-x)W_{C}(-x)]$

Where $W_{C}$ is the weight enumerator $\displaystyle W_C= \sum_{i=0}^{n} A_{i}(C)x^i$.

I can't find a counterexample about this relation so I assume that it must be true but I have no idea how to show this. Any hint and help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: It would help the question meet our quality standards if you explained your work on a small case in detail and/or provided other context as described in [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: And for a hint: How is a word of weight $w$ of $\overline{C}$ gotten from a word of $C$? Split into cases according to the parity of $w$. In one case there are two possible ways. Show that in both cases the enumeration matches with what the formula for $W_{\overline{C}}$ suggests. Just rewrite the higlighted equality in terms of both $A_i(C)$ and $A_i(\overline{C})$. Polynomial multiplication is all you need. This looks like a rather standard exercise, so I'm not going to say more at this time.